# C++ error: cast from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ loses precision

Tags: c++

I started learning C++ a few days ago.

I want to set `dog.age` using user input.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dog{
    public:
        dog();
        ~dog();
        int getAge();
        void setAge(int a);

    protected:
        int age;
};

dog::dog(){

}

dog::~dog(){

}

int dog::getAge(){
    return age;
}

void dog::setAge(int a){
    age = a;
}

int main(){
    dog myDog;
    char myString[2];
    int age;

    cout<<"How old is the dog? ";
    cin.getline(myString,2,'\n');

    age = (int)myString;
    myDog.setAge(age);
    cout<<"The dog is "<<myDog.getAge()<<" years old!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
error: cast from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
  age = (int)myString;`
```

Even if I remove `(int)`, it fails.

Why won't my program cast `myString` as an `int`?

OPTIONAL: If I'm doing something else wrong with constructing classes, feel free to tell me. I'd like to kick bad habits early.

Comment: You cannot convert to a number from a string using a simple cast.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What other steps must I take?

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a string to an int that way. `myString` is of type `char[]`, which the cast decays to `char*`, which is then converted to an `int`.

The standard library contains some methods that can convert from string to `int`.

Example: [`std::atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)